# docking the computer to station when locked restarts the session

Tags: power-management, dock-station

I'm running Archlinux and XFCE laptop, with lightdm and I have a strange problem. I'll try to describe it the best I can :

- undock the laptop
- close lid screen => this locks my session
- redock the laptop
- open it : you have to enter password to unlock
- but instead of getting my session where I left it, I get a new session !

Doing the same, just by plugging the power connector instead of docking does not reproduce the problem.
If the session is unlocked when I dock, the problem does not happen.

debugging xfce-power-manager didn't show me any strange issue. My docking station is from HP.

Any hints would help me.